# Как записать в java двумерный массив. таблица умножения?

Tags: java

в метод public static int[][] multiple(int size)

size - указывает на размер таблицы. В ячейки массива нужно записать элементы таблицы умножения. Элементы получать перемножением индексов.первая ячейка индекса начинается с 0. Это нужно учитывать при заполнении таблицы.

```java
public static int[][] multiple(int size) {
    int rsl = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < i + 1; q++) {
        rsl = (i + 1) * (q + 1);
        }
    }
    return rsl;
}
```

в чём ошибка?

Comment: есть такой тест@Test
    public void when2on2() {
        int size = 2;
        int[][] result = Matrix.multiple(size);
        int[][] expected = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}};
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, result);
    }

Comment: Так может быт вы нам скажете в чём ошибка, ну кроме возвращаемого типа в `int[][]`, а фактического `int`

Comment: так и спрашиваю в чём моя ошибка,

Comment: Эту ошибку вам компилятор показывает. Грех не читать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы двумерный массив забыли создать.

Подобный пример:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


class Matrix {
public static int[][] multiple(int size) {
    
    int[][] mas = new int[size][size];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < size; q++) {
           mas[i][q] = (i + 1) * (q + 1);
        }
    }
    return mas;
}
}


public class Hello{
     public static void main(String []args){
         
        Matrix tmp = new Matrix();
        int[][] output = tmp.multiple(2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. Поставьте плюсик слева.

Comment: Это где? Я новый пользователь

Comment: Слева, стрелка вверх.

Comment: Сделал, но ничего не отображается